# Aborted SQL 2008 R2 Upgrade

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have tried to upgrade SQL Server 2008 R2 (Which has 4 databases) to SQL Server 2012.  During the upgrade, the upgrade program hung up and got killed.  Now I have a database at version 698 which is neither good for 2008 R2 nor 2012.  Unfortunately this is the only database with a backup 6 months old (so restoring a backup is not an option as we would lose 6 months of development).  When I attach to 2012, it cannot continue from version 698.  When I attach to 2008 R2, It is attached fine but cannot read any objects in db

Please advise.